# How to find the `base` of a record array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, recarray, structured-array

How is `base` determined for record arrays?
The [docs seem](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.recarray.base.html) to describe the same behavior as regular arrays, but that's not what it is.
Here's a simple array, and a record array created from it.

```
>>> arr = np.zeros(10, dtype=[('a', float), ('b', int), ('c', int)])
>>> rec = arr.view(np.recarray)
```

The base of the record array is correctly set

```
>>> arr is rec
False

>>> arr is rec.base
True
```

The `base` is correctly set for field accesses of the regular array.

```
>>> arr['a'].base is arr
True
```

However, for the record array I can't determine what the base is.  It's not the regular array, the record array, `None`, or anything else that I've tried.

```
>>> rec['a'].base is arr
False

>>> rec['a'].base is rec
False

>>> rec['a'].base is None
False

>>> rec['a'].base is rec['a']
False

>>> rec['a'].base is rec['a'].base
False

>>> f = rec['a']
>>> f.base is f
False
```

It behaves as expected for indexing slices

```
>>> arr[:3].base is arr
True

>>> rec[:3].base is rec
True
```

And it definitely still points to the same memory

```
>>> arr[0]
(0., 0, 0)

>>> rec['a'] = 1

>>> arr[0]
(1., 0, 0)
```

So, how can the actual base of a record array be found?

Comment: As far as I can tell `recarray` doesn't add much, other than the attributes style of field access.  As for checking the data buffer location, I like to use `.__array_interface__['data']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "actual base" is still the `base` attribute. If you want to follow the `base` chain recursively, go ahead:

```
def recursive_base(arr):
    while arr.base is not None:
        arr = arr.base
    return arr
```

If you want to see why `rec['a'].base is not rec`, then take a look at [`recarray.__getitem__`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.15.1/numpy/core/records.py#L504):

```
def __getitem__(self, indx):
    obj = super(recarray, self).__getitem__(indx)

    # copy behavior of getattr, except that here
    # we might also be returning a single element
    if isinstance(obj, ndarray):
        if obj.dtype.fields:
            obj = obj.view(type(self))
            if issubclass(obj.dtype.type, nt.void):
                return obj.view(dtype=(self.dtype.type, obj.dtype))
            return obj
        else:
            return obj.view(type=ndarray)
    else:
        # return a single element
        return obj
```

In your case, the returned object is a view of the result returned by `ndarray.__getitem__`, and the `base` is the object returned by `ndarray.__getitem__`. Generally, though, it's not guaranteed whether NumPy will flatten the `base` chain when setting a new array's `base`.